# Objects cannot be selected after canvas is resized

Tags: fabricjs

I have a Fabric canvas inside a modal window that can be resized by the user. To resize the canvas, I use `canvas.setDimensions({width:w, height:h});` taking `w` and `h` from the modal size.

When the canvas is resized, for each object in the canvas I change proportionally their size and location. I calculate a factor to apply to each object's `top/left/width/height` using the original and new canvas sizes. This code runs every time the canvas is resized:

```
        canvas.getObjects().map(function(o) {

            // calculate factors
            var factorW = (newCanvasDim.width/o.data.canvasW);
            var factorH = (newCanvasDim.height/o.data.canvasH)

            // calculate new position
            var left = o.data.origL * factorW;
            var top = o.data.origT * factorH;
            o.setLeft(left);
            o.setTop(top);

            // calculate new size
            var width = o.data.origW * factorW;
            var height = o.data.origH * factorH;
            o.setWidth(width);
            o.setHeight(height);

            canvas.renderAll();
            canvas.calcOffset();

        });
```

Resizing works fine, all the objects change their dimensions correctly.The problem is that **most objects cannot be selected after the canvas is resized**. Also, clicking on empty areas of the canvas sometimes selects objects.

I tried using `canvas.calcOffset();` after I change each object attributes (see code above) but it doesn't help. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `setCoords()` instead of `calcOffset()` on each of the objects (not the canvas) after you resize each object - in your resized canvas :-).

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/When-to-call-setCoords.